# "No fortunes found" error

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg, root, fortune

So, I have installed `fortune` on my Rackspace server but if I run it without any arguments it says

```
No fortunes found
```

I installed the package as root so there shouldn't be a permissions issue.  The directory `/usr/share/games/fortunes` doesn't even exist which is where it's supposed to store the fortunes. I thought it might be a Rackspace package issue so I install the latest stable deb package with `dpkg` from `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/fortune-mod_1.99.1-7_amd64.deb`.  I've tried uninstalling `fortune` and `fortune-mod` and re-installing them with `aptitude` to no avail.  What could the issue be?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Just a basic `sudo apt-get install fortune`. I also tried `sudo apt-get autoremove fortune fortune-mod` and then re-installed with `sudo aptitude install fortune`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the fortune-mod package only contains the server/engine, not the fortunes to serve.  You need to install a package containing actual fortunes as well (try `fortunes-min`)

Comment: So I ran `sudo apt-cache search fortune` and there was a package called `fortunes` along with tons of other language packages which had them in every different language. Strangely, I was able to install `fortunes` without installing `fortune` and vice versa.  I believe the fortune data files are listed as a dependency in the normal repository, this must just be a Rackspace thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The package [`fortune`](https://linux.die.net/man/6/fortune) (or `fortune-mod`) only contain the program to display the fortune cookies, not the cookies (texts) themselves.

You need to additionally install a `fortunes*` package. Which ones are available for your system can be easily checked with the command `apt-cache search "^fortunes"`. On my system, the output is:

```
fortunes - Data files containing fortune cookies
fortunes-bg - Bulgarian data files for fortune
fortunes-bofh-excuses - BOFH excuses for fortune
fortunes-br - Data files with fortune cookies in Portuguese
fortunes-cs - Czech and Slovak data files for fortune
fortunes-de - German data files for fortune
fortunes-debian-hints - Debian Hints for fortune
fortunes-eo - Collection of esperanto fortunes.
fortunes-eo-ascii - Collection of esperanto fortunes (ascii encoding).
fortunes-eo-iso3 - Collection of esperanto fortunes (ISO3 encoding).
fortunes-es - Spanish fortune database
fortunes-es-off - Spanish fortune cookies (Offensive section)
fortunes-fr - French fortunes cookies
fortunes-ga - Irish (Gaelige) data files for fortune
fortunes-it - Data files containing Italian fortune cookies
fortunes-it-off - Data files containing Italian fortune cookies, offensive section
fortunes-mario - Fortunes files from Mario
fortunes-min - Data files containing selected fortune cookies
fortunes-off - Data files containing offensive fortune cookies
fortunes-pl - Polish data files for fortune
fortunes-ru - Russian data files for fortune
fortunes-spam - fortunes taken from SPAM messages
fortunes-ubuntu-server - Ubuntu server tips for fortune
```

Install those packages that interest you, usually you want `fortunes-min` (small package of about 60 kB with few fortune cookies) or `fortunes` (larger package of about 1 MB with over 15,000 cookies).

The others are either localized (German or Spanish cookies for example) or cover a specific topic only (e.g. spam or offensive). You may of course install multiple fortunes packages.

If you install a language package, these are installed on a subfolder of `/usr/share/games/fortunes/` so you may need to prefix it to the database name:

```
fortune -e -s es/asimov.fortunes ubuntu-server-tips
```

---

Oh, and don't forget: `fortune` works best in combination with `cowsay`! :D

```
$ fortune | cowsay
 _____________________________________
/ A handful of patience is worth more \
\ than a bushel of brains.            /
 -------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Comment: in order to display it to every new terminal, add the following lines to your ~/.bashrc: 
    "if [ -x /usr/games/cowsay -a -x /usr/games/fortune ]; then
        fortune | cowthink
    fi"

Comment: To have only short ones and in one line `fortune -s -n 80 | paste -s | awk '{$2=$2};1'`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (and installing fortunes didn't work)

but if I run:

```
fortune -ao
```

The fortune program works as expected...

(don't know why...)

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer the *original* Unix 5 fortune cookie datafile,
you can find it here:

[fortune cookie](https://github.com/giorgossaridakis/fortune-cookie)

It comes with my small app in C to read it. Change FORTUNEFILEPATH in line 5 (fortune.c) to point to where you want to keep fortune.dat.

This has 10155 entries.

I wish luck :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do below commands and it will work:

```
$ strfile fortunes/data/fortunes
$ strfile fortunes/data/chinese
$ strfile fortunes/data/tang300
$ strfile fortunes/data/song100
$ strfile fortunes/data/diet
```